# Why is String.equals much slower for non-identical (but equal) String objects?

Tags: java, string, performance, equals

I'm delving into the question of is `String.equals()` really *that* bad and while trying to do some benchmarking of it came across some surprising results.

Using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), I wrote up a simple test (code and pom at end) which sees how many times the function can be run in 1 second.

```
Benchmark                                Mode  Samples          Score   Score error  Units
c.s.SimpleBenchmark.testEqualsIntern    thrpt        5  698910949.710  47115846.650  ops/s
c.s.SimpleBenchmark.testEqualsNew       thrpt        5     529118.774     21164.872  ops/s
c.s.SimpleBenchmark.testIsEmpty         thrpt        5  470846539.546  19922172.099  ops/s
```

The this is a 1300x factor between `testEqualsIntern` and `testEqualsNew` which is frankly *quite* surprising to me.

The code for [String.equals()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) does have a test for the same object, which would kick the identical (interned in this case) string objects out quite quickly.  I just have have significant difficulty believing that the additional code which appears to amount to walking over an array of size 1 for the two tests and comparing elements is *that* much of a performance hit.

I've also put in a test with another simple method call in the String to make sure I wasn't seeing something that is too crazy.

```
package com.shagie;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

public class SimpleBenchmark {
    public final static int ITERATIONS = 1000;
    public final static String EMPTY = "";
    public final static String NEW_EMPTY = new String("");

    @Benchmark
    public int testEqualsIntern() {
        int count = 0;
        String str = EMPTY;

        for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            if(str.equals(EMPTY)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int testEqualsNew() {
        int count = 0;
        String str = NEW_EMPTY;

        for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            if(str.equals(EMPTY)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int testIsEmpty() {
        int count = 0;
        String str = NEW_EMPTY;

        for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            if(str.isEmpty()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
          .include(".*" + SimpleBenchmark.class.getSimpleName() + ".*")
          .warmupIterations(5)
          .measurementIterations(5)
          .forks(1)
          .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }
}
```

The .pom for maven (to quickly set it up yourself if you wish to reproduce this):

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.shagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>bench</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>String Benchmarks with JMH</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jmh.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
            <version>${jmh.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jmh.version>0.9.5</jmh.version>
        <javac.target>1.6</javac.target>
        <uberjar.name>benchmarks</uberjar.name>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>${javac.target}</compilerVersion>
                    <source>${javac.target}</source>
                    <target>${javac.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${uberjar.name}</finalName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

This was auto generated with (appropriate tweaks made for group and artifact):

```
$ mvn archetype:generate \
          -DinteractiveMode=false \
          -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openjdk.jmh \
          -DarchetypeArtifactId=jmh-java-benchmark-archetype \
          -DgroupId=org.sample \
          -DartifactId=test \
          -Dversion=1.0
```

To run the tests:

```
$ mvn clean install
$ java -jar target/benchmarks.jar ".*SimpleBenchmark.*" -wi 5 -i 5 -f 1
```

As it will be a question, the Java version this is running under:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

The hardware (which might come into question) is OS X, 10.9.4 on an Intel Xeon processor.

Comment: Looks like now we have a reason to get James Gosling to stackoverflow. lol :-)

Comment: If the `String` reference's aren't equal, the method has to do an `instaceof` check, has to cast the `Object` reference to a `String`, it has to do a number of field accesses, array accesses, assignments, and equality checks. It all amounts to a non trivial equality check.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: And that's not true of *any* of the other tests?  Why?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Speaking strictly within the `String#equals(Object)` and `String#isEmpty()` methods, no. The former would simply compare a reference and return `true`, the latter would have a field access and compare and return a the result.

Comment: Could you try with a newer version of java, say 8?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and I'll give you that, but that 1300x difference in performance is *still* surprising to me.  I am most curious if my benchmark is constructed improperly, or if there really is a thing of 'using `.equals("")` for empty string testing is really really bad compared to alternatives.

Comment: +1 for Java 8, it's an interesting question and may as well be investigated on most recent JVM impl (even if the results differ a bit from one another).

Comment: @aioobe I can work on installing it on my system, though it will take some time making sure I don't break Java for the rest of the system (in the recent past installing Java 8 on macs did some ugly things with fonts (as an obvious issue - there may have been others)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing equality against a new String does not have a ridiculous performance hit. The effect you're seeing is simply that Hotspot is able to optimize away the loop in one case, but not the other.

Here's the hotspot assembly dump of `testEqualsIntern` from OpenJDK 7 (IcedTea7 2.1.7) (7u3-2.1.7-1) 64bit server showing the loopless result (similar code is generated for `testIsEmpty`):

```
Decoding compiled method 0x00007fb360a1a0d0:
Code:
[Entry Point]
[Constants]
  # {method} 'testEqualsIntern' '()I' in 'Test'
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  0x00007fb360a1a200: mov    0x8(%rsi),%r10d
  0x00007fb360a1a204: cmp    %r10,%rax
  0x00007fb360a1a207: jne    0x00007fb3609f38a0  ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fb360a1a20d: data32 xchg %ax,%ax
[Verified Entry Point]
  0x00007fb360a1a210: push   %rbp
  0x00007fb360a1a211: sub    $0x10,%rsp
  0x00007fb360a1a215: nop                       ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - Test::testEqualsIntern@-1 (line 8)
  0x00007fb360a1a216: mov    $0x3e8,%eax
  0x00007fb360a1a21b: add    $0x10,%rsp
  0x00007fb360a1a21f: pop    %rbp
  0x00007fb360a1a220: test   %eax,0x6232dda(%rip)        # 0x00007fb366c4d000
                                                ;   {poll_return}
  0x00007fb360a1a226: retq
```

When you compare 1000 iterations of one thing with 1 iteration of another, it's not surprising that the results differ by a factor of 1000.

I ran the same test after adding four zeroes to ITERATIONS, and as expected, `testEqualsIntern` took equally long as before while `testEqualsNew` was too slow to wait for.

Answer (score 6):

It is very easy to write flawed micro benchmarks... and you get trapped.

The only way to know what happen is to look at the assembly code. You have to check by yourself if the resulting code is what you expected or if some unwanted magic happened. Let's try to do it together. You have to use `addProfile(LinuxPerfAsmProfiler.class)` to see the assembly code.

What is the assembly code for `testEqualsIntern`:

```
....[Hottest Region 1]..............................................................................
[0x7fb9e11acda0:0x7fb9e11acdc8] in org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop

                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@19 (line 103)
                  0x00007fb9e11acd82: movzbl 0x94(%rdx),%r11d   ;*getfield isDone
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@29 (line 105)
                  0x00007fb9e11acd8a: mov    $0x2,%ebp
                  0x00007fb9e11acd8f: test   %r11d,%r11d
                  0x00007fb9e11acd92: jne    0x00007fb9e11acdcc  ;*ifeq
                                                                 ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@32 (line 105)
                  0x00007fb9e11acd94: nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
                  0x00007fb9e11acd9c: xchg   %ax,%ax            ;*aload
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@13 (line 103)
6.50%    3.37%    0x00007fb9e11acda0: mov    0xb0(%rdi),%r11d   ;*getfield i1
                                                                ; - org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole::consume@2 (line 350)
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@19 (line 103)
0.06%    0.05%    0x00007fb9e11acda7: mov    0xb4(%rdi),%r10d   ;*getfield i2
                                                                ; - org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole::consume@15 (line 350)
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@19 (line 103)
0.06%    0.09%    0x00007fb9e11acdae: cmp    $0x3e8,%r10d
0.03%             0x00007fb9e11acdb5: je     0x00007fb9e11acdf1  ;*return
                                                                ; - org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole::consume@38 (line 354)
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@19 (line 103)
48.85%   44.47%    0x00007fb9e11acdb7: movzbl 0x94(%rdx),%ecx    ;*getfield isDone
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@29 (line 105)
0.33%    0.62%    0x00007fb9e11acdbe: add    $0x1,%rbp          ; OopMap{r9=Oop rbx=Oop rdi=Oop rdx=Oop off=226}
                                                                ;*ifeq
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@32 (line 105)
0.03%    0.05%    0x00007fb9e11acdc2: test   %eax,0x16543238(%rip)        # 0x00007fb9f76f0000
                                                                ;   {poll}
42.31%   49.43%    0x00007fb9e11acdc8: test   %ecx,%ecx
                   0x00007fb9e11acdca: je     0x00007fb9e11acda0  ;*aload_2
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@35 (line 106)
                  0x00007fb9e11acdcc: mov    $0x7fb9f706fe40,%r10
                  0x00007fb9e11acdd6: callq  *%r10              ;*invokestatic nanoTime
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@36 (line 106)
                  0x00007fb9e11acdd9: mov    %rbp,0x10(%rbx)    ;*putfield operations
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@51 (line 108)
                  0x00007fb9e11acddd: mov    %rax,0x28(%rbx)    ;*putfield stopTime
                                                                ; - org.sample.generated.MyBenchmark_testEqualsIntern::testEqualsIntern_thrpt_jmhLoop@39 (line 106)
....................................................................................................
```

As you may know, JMH takes your benchmark code and inserts it into its own measurement loop. You can easily see the generated code by looking into the `target/generated-sources` folder. You have to know how this code looks like to be able to compare it to the assembly.

The interesting part is here:

```
public void testEqualsIntern_avgt_jmhLoop(InfraControl control, RawResults result, MyBenchmark_1_jmh l_mybenchmark0_0, Blackhole_1_jmh l_blackhole1_1) throws Throwable {
    long operations = 0;
    long realTime = 0;
    result.startTime = System.nanoTime();
    do {
        l_blackhole1_1.consume(l_mybenchmark0_0.testEqualsIntern());
        operations++;
    } while(!control.isDone);
    result.stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    result.realTime = realTime;
    result.operations = operations;
}
```

Ok you see this nice do/while loop that does two things:

- invoking you function
- invoking consume to prevent Hotspot unwanted optimization ?

Now lets go back to the assembly. Try to find theses three operations in it (loop, consume, and your code). Can you ?

You can see the JMH loop, it is the `0x00007fb9e11acdb7: movzbl 0x94(%rdx),%ecx    ;*getfield isDone` and the following jump.

You can see the blackhole, it is from `0x00007fb9e11acda0` to `0x00007fb9e11acdb5:`

But where is your code ? Its gone. You did not follow JMH good practices and you allowed Hotspot to remove your code. You are benchmarking a NOOP. BTW have you ever tried to benchmark a NOOP ? It is a good thing to do, when you see a number close to this you know that you have to be very careful.

You can do the same analysis for the second benchmark. I did not read its assembly code carefully but you will be able to spot your for loop and the call to equals. You can them read JMH samples again to try to avoid such issue.

TL;DR Writing correct micro/nano benchmarks is crazily difficult and you should double check that you know what you have measured. The assembly is the only way to go. Watch all presentations and read all the blog posts from Aleksey to learn more. He is doing great job. And finally, such measurements are almost always useless in real life but a good learning tool.

Comment: The key message is not as "obvious" as in the other answer, but +1 for the detailed analysis of what JMH acually does.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation would seem to be (in the first case, the `intern()`'d one) the JVM is able to test reference equality which is a direct numerical comparison.

In contrast, the test for non-reference equality (value equality) must iterate the character sequences of the two String(s). Your observed results are not quite as significant as you believe. There is JIT and other optimizations going on and the performance would likely improve in practice (as not every String is equal, and it can short circuit when they aren't).

Finally, micro-benchmarks are notoriously unreliable. But you have found a performance optimization that is built into the JVM by design. The reference equality check **is** that much faster.

Comment: Ahem, it's not premature optimization if the need for such a comparison exists, profiling identifies it as a performance bottleneck, and there is a *three orders of magnitude difference in performance.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're right of course. It's a garden variety *optimization*.

Comment: I expect the JIT to get involved, especially with `isEmpty()` and inlining it. I am particularly interested in the test for empty string (something that is commonly done) and if I am indeed seeing a 1000x difference between `.equals("")` and `.isEmpty()`.  Static analysis tools warn about this and claim that `.isEmpty()` is more performant - I wanted to see how much that was the case.

Comment: @MichaelT Do you have debug compiled in? That might effect the performance. What platforms are you going to test? What implementations? This is not a trivial problem you are investigating. Finally, have you considered the performance of `str.length() == 0`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The java version is the one bundled in OS X (I don't *believe* it has debug). At this time, I only have my mac available for testing.  Juggling Java versions in the past has caused some headaches and I'm hesitant to do it off hand (though I'm curious about the result for other VMs on other platforms).  The full benchmarking suite is 3x larger than this one (I don't want to paste 180 lines of code when 60 will demonstrate it) and I do consider other empty string tests: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17193796#17193796 (and non-trivial problems are the fun ones)

Comment: @MichaelT As long as you know what you're getting into. Also, consider the compiler flags `-g` (debug) and `-O` (optimize).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Who cares about three orders of magnitude when the slower operation is one or two nanosecond in the benchmark ?  An L2 cache hit is ~10ns and going to the RAM is ~100ns. In real life the throughput will be limited by memory latency & bandwidth.

Comment: @ClémentMATHIEU: Sounds like you didn't read my entire comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sounds like I misread your entire comment. My apologizes, I fully agree with you :)

Answer (score -2):

```
public int testEqualsIntern() {
    int count = 0;
    String str = EMPTY;

    for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        if(str.equals(EMPTY)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

here str.equals(EMPTY) will first check equality by == and it will return true, as both str and EMPTY both has same reference and are in string pool and the operation will become faster, but in case

```
public int testEqualsNew() {
    int count = 0;
    String str = NEW_EMPTY;

    for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        if(str.equals(EMPTY)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

EMPTY string is in string pool while NEW_EMPTY is not part of pool, and both has different references as EMPTY one is literal constants and NEW_EMPTY is not. so equals() first try to compare equality by == which will return false as both has different references, and the it will check content, so in this case equals() will take more time.